# C++, Nothing in the output

Tags: c++, terminal, output, std, cout

I am new to C++ and coded my first main.cpp but I got an error, not exactly an error, it is a logical error, I guess because I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream> // including the iostream
using namespace std; // using the std namespace

int main() { // starting the main function
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl; // My favorite line of code in all the of languages
    return 0; // returning 0 to stop the function execution
}
```

In the terminal I expected

```
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop> g++ main.cpp
Hello World!

C:\Users\DELL\Desktop>
```

But it is just showing:

```
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop> g++ main.cpp

C:\Users\DELL\Desktop>
```

No output is coming, but when I try in Code::Blocks, it is working just fine! In vscode terminal, the same problem but when I run the file, it is working again! Why is it not working? I tried it in Command Prompt, installed the Windows Terminal, and tried it in that also (keeping the terminal as Command Prompt, cause I don't know what PowerShell is and how to use it) but any method is not working.

Please tell me what to do, I am new to c++ and know only some things amount it.

Comment: g++ only compiles your code. You need to actually run it to get any output https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compiling-with-g-plus-plus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `g++ main.cpp` creates the file a.out or a.exe. After that file is created you need to run it by the command `./a.out` on Linux and Mac or `a.exe` on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for helping, with your help, I wrote this line of code which helps me do everything in just one line `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe && main.exe`, this just compiles the `min.exe` and gives the output in the `main.exe` file, and then runs the `main.exe` command to run the file and get the output in just one line.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, after g++ "file.cpp", you get an output file in your current working directory, which is the executable. C++ is compiled, not interpreted.

That output file is the executable, which by default will be "a.out", with gcc/g++. You can use the option "-o" to specify the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

`g++ main.cpp` will compile the file and produce `a.exe`, you just need to type `a.exe` in the terminal and it will print `Hello World!`.